# Issues with spring and Spark Streaming together

Tags: spring-boot, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am working on a data analytics project. I am new in Spark. I have created a SpringBoot project in which I am using some Spark Streaming consumers which consumes data from Kafka topic.

I have used all components like Kafka, Spark in the same SpringBoot application. Below is SpringBoot Main class in which I am initializing Spark Streaming job using a command line runner.

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableCaching
    public class SpringApplication
    {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.class, args);
    }

     @Bean
    public EnrichEventSparkConsumerRunner sparkEnrichEventConsumerRunner()
    {
         return new EnrichEventSparkConsumerRunner();
    }


    @Bean
    public RawEventSparkConsumerRunner sparkRawEventConsumerRunner()
    {
        return new RawEventSparkConsumerRunner();
    }
    }


 public class EnrichEventSparkConsumerRunner implements CommandLineRunner
    {

    @Autowired
    JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext;

    @Autowired
    EnrichEventSparkConsumer enrichEventSparkConsumer;

   @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        // start Raw Event Spark Cosnumer.
        JobContextImpl jobContext = new JobContextImpl(javaStreamingContext);

        // start Enrich Event Spark Consumer.
        enrichEventSparkConsumer.startEnrichEventConsumer(jobContext.streamingctx());
    }

    }


  public class RawEventSparkConsumerRunner implements CommandLineRunner
    {

    @Autowired
    JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext;

    @Autowired
    RawEventSparkConsumer rawEventSparkConsumer;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        // start Raw Event Spark Cosnumer.
        JobContextImpl jobContext = new JobContextImpl(javaStreamingContext);
        rawEventSparkConsumer.sparkRawEventConsumer(jobContext.streamingctx());
    }

    }
```

**RawEventSparkConsumer.java** - In this SparkStreaming class, We are consuming data from Kafka topic, enriching the data and saving that data into elastic and also we are sending that enriched data to next Kafka topic which is consumed by EnrichEventSparkConsumer.

```
@Component
public class RawEventSparkConsumer implements Serializable
{
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RawEventSparkConsumer.class);

    @Autowired
    private ElasticSearchServiceImpl dataModelServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    private EnrichEventKafkaProducer enrichEventKafkaProducer;

    @Autowired
    private SparkConfiguration sparkConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    private RawAttributesConfig rawAttConfig;

    private static  ObjectMapper mapper;

    public void sparkRawEventConsumer(JavaStreamingContext streamingContext)
    {

        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList(sparkConfiguration.getRawEventTopic());
        Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashedMap();
        kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", sparkConfiguration.getBootStrapServers());
        kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
        kafkaParams.put("group.id", "group1");
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest");
        kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", true);

        JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> rawEventRDD = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(streamingContext,
            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(), ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));

        JavaDStream<String> dStream = rawEventRDD.map((x) -> x.value());

        /*
         * JavaDStream<EnrichEventDataModel> enrichEventRdd = dStream.map((raw) -> { BaseDataModel csvDataModel =
         * mapper.readValue(raw, BaseDataModel.class); return new EnrichEventDataModel(csvDataModel); });
         */

        JavaDStream<List<Map<String, Object>>> enrichEventRdd = dStream.map(convertIntoMapList);

        enrichEventRdd.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
            logger.info("Inside rawEventRDD.foreachRDD = = = " + rdd.count());
            sendEnrichEventToKafkaTopic(rdd.collect());
        });

        streamingContext.start();

        try {
            streamingContext.awaitTermination();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("RawEvent consumer SparkStreaming job started.");
    }

    HashMap<String, UserIndexDto> userMap = new HashMap();

    private void sendEnrichEventToKafkaTopic(List<List<Map<String, Object>>> list)
    {
        if (enrichEventKafkaProducer != null && list != null && list.size() > 0)
            try {
                logger.info("sendEnrichEventToKafkaTopic, csv raw log count: "+ list.size());
                list.parallelStream().forEach(mapList -> {
                    logger.info("sendEnrichEventToKafkaTopic -- mapListmapList, mapList: "+ mapList.size());

                    if (Objects.nonNull(mapList) && mapList.size() > 0) {
                        List<Map<String, Object>> enrichedMapList = mapList.parallelStream().map(mapData -> {
                            if (mapData.containsKey(rawAttConfig.getAccountname())) {
                                String accountName = String.valueOf(mapData.get(rawAttConfig.getAccountname()));
                                if(accountName != null) {
                                    accountName = accountName.trim();
                                }
                                if (accountName != null && accountName.length() > 0 && !userMap.containsKey(accountName)) {
                                    accountName = accountName.split("@")[0];

                                    List<User> userList = dataModelServiceImpl.getUser(accountName,"u_employeeId");
                                    if (userList != null && userList.size() > 0) {
                                        User user = userList.get(0);

                                        if(!user.getU_userId().equalsIgnoreCase(accountName)) {
                                            List<User> userList1 = dataModelServiceImpl.getUser(accountName,"u_email");
                                            if(userList1 != null && userList1.size() > 0) {
                                                User user1 = userList1.get(0);
                                                UserIndexDto userdto1 = new UserIndexDto();
                                                userdto1.setUserId(user1.getU_email());
                                                userdto1.setEmpId(user1.getU_employeeId());
                                                userMap.put(userdto1.getUserId(), userdto1); 
                                            }
                                        }else {
                                            UserIndexDto userdto = new UserIndexDto();
                                            userdto.setUserId(user.getU_userId());
                                            userdto.setEmpId(user.getU_employeeId());
                                             userMap.put(userdto.getUserId(), userdto);
                                         }
                                        writeToLogsFile("Enriching RawEvent using ElasticIndex for accountName="
                                            + userList.get(0).getU_employeeId(), Constants.INFO);
                                    }else {

                                            List<User> userList1 = dataModelServiceImpl.getUser(accountName,"u_email");
                                            if(userList1 != null && userList1.size() > 0) {
                                                User user1 = userList1.get(0);
                                                UserIndexDto userdto1 = new UserIndexDto();
                                                 userdto1.setUserId(user1.getU_email());
                                                userdto1.setEmpId(user1.getU_employeeId());
                                                userMap.put(userdto1.getUserId(), userdto1); 

                                            }

                                    } 
                                }

                                UserIndexDto userdto = userMap.get(accountName);
                                mapData.put("userId", userdto != null ? userdto.getUserId() : null );
                                mapData.put("empId", userdto != null ? userdto.getEmpId() : null);

                               // writeToLogsFile("Enriching RawEvent using Map for accountName=" + (userdto != null ? userdto.getUserId() : ""),
                               //     Constants.INFO);

                            } else {
                                mapData.put("userId", null);
                                mapData.put("empId", null);
                            }
                            mapData.put("enrichEventId", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                            saveDataToEasticSearch(mapData);
                            return mapData;
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
                        //saveDataToElasticSearch(enrichedMapList);
                        processEnrichEvents(enrichedMapList);
                    }
                });

            } catch (Exception e) {
                writeToLogsFile(e.getMessage(), Constants.ERROR);
            }
    }


    private void saveDataToEasticSearch(Map<String, Object> mapData) {
        if(Objects.nonNull(mapData)) {
            dataModelServiceImpl.saveEnrichModel(mapData);
        }
    }

    static Function convertIntoMapList = new Function<String, List<Map<String, Object>>>()
    {

        @Override
        public List<Map<String, Object>> call(String raw) throws Exception
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return mapper.readValue(raw, new TypeReference<List<HashMap<String, Object>>>(){});
        }


    };



    private void processEnrichEvents(List<Map<String, Object>> enrichedMapList)
    {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            enrichEventKafkaProducer.sendEnrichEvent(enrichedMapList);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void saveDataToElasticSearch(List<Map<String, Object>> enrichedMapList)
    {
        if (!enrichedMapList.isEmpty())
            dataModelServiceImpl.saveAllEnrichModel(enrichedMapList);
    }

    private void writeToLogsFile(String message, String loglevel)
    {
        if (loglevel.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.ERROR)) {
            logger.error(message);
        } else if (loglevel.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.INFO)) {
            logger.info(message);
        }
    }
```

Now I have created a jar for it using **mvn clean package** command and running that jar using **java -jar** command which initialize Spark job using command line runner. It's working fine even we did POC with that.

Now we want to run Spark in a cluster environment. So I have some queries related to it. I have searched a lot but did not get the right way to do it. Below is the issues and queries -

1. Is it a right way that we are using Spark Streaming through comamnd line runner?
2. As i read for running cluster env we have to submit spark streamign using spark-submit command. How 
   can i do it in my current project. Issue is that As i know for Spark-submit we need a main method. So 
   what changes do i need to make in it for Spark-Submit.
3. We are saving the data into elastic using elastic API. is it a right way to do it?
4. Please have a look to this line **sendEnrichEventToKafkaTopic(rdd.collect());** in which we are calling .collect on rdd . I read that when we call .collect then this thing run on the master node. So we have to avoid .collect. So what's the other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few guidelines, not maybe the best option, due to the lack of problem context:

1. The way to do it is to have a Spark cluster, or spark as a Service which is able to act as a Server and application could submit spark apps (or spark jobs) to that cluster. You could pack your application as a single fat jar and upload it to cluster
2. Spark app should be decoupled as much as possible from the Spring context. If you don't to that one way is to create an ApplicationContext in the main method of the Spark App with the proper configuration and in the spark places where you have spring dependencies call `context.getBean`. Interacting with the Spark Cluster, which was the Spark app is either via spark-submit, or you can use `SparkLauncher` which acts as a Spark client.
3. Where you store the output of your business logic is application specific. You could save to whatever data store fits your application requirements
4. `sendEnrichEventToKafkaTopic(rdd.collect())` can be replace with something like 
   `rdd.toDF.write.format("kafka")` to avoid the collect